# how to integrate jbootstrap to joomla cms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am new to joomla, could any one tell me how to integrate **jbootstrap** that i have searched from Google to the joomla cms.

It is hard to find how to integrate into the exciting joomla design.

Is **jbootstrap** a template or plugin that have the features of **Twitter Bootstrap**?

Is it suitable for custom responsive design with **Twitter Bootstrap**?

[Link to JBootstrap](http://jbootstrap.extly.com/)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, save yourself some hassle and just use Joomla 3.0. It already integrates Bootstrap into the core of Joomla and allows you to use any template that works with 3.0. It is technically still beta software, but should be able to work well in a lot of cases.

Comment: @DavidFritsch how you integrate it? is this a plugin or whole template or a theme which you have to attach in our joomla template folder...

Comment: Download Joomla! 3.0. Check the protostar template. Take it as a reference on building a Joomla! template and using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the package, create a new folder in your template folder (call it "bootstrap" for example), then extract the JBootstrap package in there. So your folder structure should look like this:

```
template_name/
     ├──bootstrap/
          ├── css/
          │   ├── bootstrap.css
          │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
          ├── js/
          │   ├── bootstrap.js
          │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
          ├── img/
              ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
              ├── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
```

Then, open your *index.php* in your **template** folder (not the root folder!!) and put this PHP code somewhere which will include the Bootstrap files.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/js/jquery-1.8.3.js");
}
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js");
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

You need to include jQuery aswell, so the first few lines check o see if it is already being imported, and it only imports it if it already isn't being done. This is a good method as multiple jQuery libraries can prevent things from working.

---

or you could as @David Fritsch said, use Joomla 3.0 which already has Bootstrap integrated in it.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the answer i have to do some changes to your code but my job is done...

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option of the JS_Wright template framework from JoomlaShack... Bootstrap nicely integrated in that already as well. (works great in Joomla 2.5.X)